# Connected App - Custom Attribute From Related Contact on User

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml

Trying to create / expose a custom attribute from the User record in a connected app through SAML. The value in question is from the Account of the related contact, thus User.Contact.Account.Custom_Field__c.

I've created a formula field on the user to reference this just fine, but in trying to create the custom attribute, it doesn't recognize that the contact relationship exists.

Does anyone know if this is a known limitation or is there a way to expose this value (related contact fields) without a custom apex class for the connected app?

EDIT: Adding Screenshots per comments
[image: Formula available for use]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more? 

I was able to create a formula field on the User object and then I see the fields in the Connected App Custom attributes!

Comment: Sure, so I'm trying to reference the Contact record of the user (these are community users). My formula compiles and is exposed as a custom attribute when selecting the field, but when I go to save, it errors saying "User.Contact" not found. So its basically not understanding the standard community/contact relationship for the user.

Comment: I created a formula field directly on the user object and then just select this formula field in the custom attribute. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @MohithShrivastava, I don't think I'm articulating well. That's what I've done, but its accepting my formula. Its not the formula field itself being the issue, its the contact relationship seemingly. I'll try to update my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava updated question with screenshots.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the screenshot! I can reproduce the error!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Is there any update on this? Is it really  a salesforce known issue?

Answer (score 1):

As of now Cross-object formula is not supported in the 'Custom Attributes' of Connected app.
PFB the link of salesforce help article link for your reference.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000340116&type=1